# Warning about unsafe content when saving wikipage using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wiki, unsafe-updates

After editing a wiki page using SharePoint Designer 2010 I have stared to get the message "Content in the embedded form field maybe changed by the server to remove unsafe content. Do you want to reload the page to see the results of the save?"

I get this error even on a empty/new wiki page so I guess it is a warning that always appear? Some user find it a bit irritating.

Anyhow...sometimes content are removed. "target=_top" seems to be unsafe and sometimes href's are removed too. What is the definition of unsafe content? Why is target=top unsafe? Sharepoint Designer removing content users might have spent hours on is not a great feature IMO. Maybe I've missed something. (It happends all the time :-)

Ivar

Answer (score 1):

It does happen all the time. This is where SharePoint thinks its smarter than the user and its dead wrong. If you use regular pages you do not get this. If I am forced to use a wiki page because of requirements I will create my web parts on a standard web part page then export/import them to my wiki page. The Wiki pages to my understanding are actually Rich HTML fields so it seems to be really finicky, I hadnt noticed it with basic tags like that before though.